# How do I convert a Time integer to a Date in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm getting this stamp from an external API:

```
1391655852
```

and I need to convert it to a Date. I have seen a lot of conversion pages on the internet and on SO, but they all seem to be going the other way. I'm not familiar with this integer format at all.

Comment: PS: Some languages supply does date to integer conversion using milliseconds from `epoch` (while ruby uses seconds from epoch), so care needs to be taken when converting date to and from integers

Comment: I think it ***is*** a duplicate. You have effectively admitted that the linked post answers your question, but that it was hard to find. This is **exactly** why we have the duplicate system: Your question acts as an excellent *signpost* for the other.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use [`Time.at`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Time.html#method-c-at) for this:

```
t = Time.at(i)
```

Answer (score 10):

I'll definitely yield to @duck's answer - in my opinion, that's the best way to convert an integer to `Time` - but if you're *explicitly* looking for a `Date`, you'll want to do a bit more work:

```
require 'date'

t = Time.at(i)
date = t.to_date
```

In the above example, `date` will be of class `Date`.